# Execute python code inside php in /var/www/html directory

Tags: php, python, tensorflow

Error coming when running a python code which is using tensorflow , inside the php code. Error is :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "Loader.py", line 5, in import tensorflow as tf 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in from tensorflow.python import * 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description) 
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: invalid ELF header
```

Few lines of Python code in which trying to execute the python code are:-

```
$temp =  shell_exec('python Loader.py 2>&1') or die('cannot run Loader.py') ;
        echo $temp;
```

Comment: Looks like your `_pywrap_tensorflow.so` from the tensorflow package is not compatible with your system or damaged.

Comment: no Instead when i run directyl from terminal , inside the /var/www/html directory , the code is running fine

Comment: If I run any executable c++ code, then it is running fine... only with tensorflow python code it is giving problem

Comment: Your PHP process might have insufficient permissions to read or execute the `.so` file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new virtual environment. Install your dependencies and then run your code.